# Eclipse is opening all files in another text editor

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, text-editor

I installed Eclipse and successfully imported my project. The problem is now when I click on any file, it opens in Geany (the default editor of my Ubuntu). I tried to change the `Open with` option but get the same result. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the associated editor for given file type by navigating to

`Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`

Comment: Is there anyway of opening other program (i.e. notepad++ etc.) inside the elipse?

Comment: @archenoo opening a program inside another program is not technically possible unless both programs were specifically designed to interface with each other. In the case of Notepad++ and Eclipse, there is no such interface. An example of such interfacing will be seen in Windows Explorer's preview pane, where the preview of Excel files are shown by Microsoft Excel, and the preview of PDF files are shown by Adobe Reader.

Comment: on the top of the eclipse editor   Window -> Preferences -> General  ->****     somtimes i just forget where the preferences are.

Answer (score 0):

I set my File Associations and that was not enough to make double clicking open the correct editor. I also had to add *.jsp as a Text mapping under Content Types. I also had to select each file that had a previous mapping and select Open With... => Default Editor.

After setting 1) the File Association; 2) Content Type and 3) Default Editor for each file, double click opens it in the editor I want.